# Get the component id or name of the component calling the getter method from the rendered attribute JSF

Tags: jsf, clientid

I need to get get the component id of the component that is calling the getter method from the rendered attribute of a JSF tag.

my intention is to build a "globalGetter" and based on the id or name field, retrieve the permission for that object from a hash map.

NOTE: i do not want to pass in the string id from the JSF implementation through EL expressions.

```
<p:commandButton style="float:right;" 
                 value="New Export" 
                 id="viewPageId" 
                 name="viewPageName"
                 rendered="#{ExportBean.globalPermission }"
                 action="#{ExportBean.resetCreateUI}">   

</p:commandButton>
```

The following is my gettter:

NOTE: the code displayed was for testing which ids I was retrieving and can server as an example of the methods i have already tried.

```
public boolean isGlobalPermission(){
         boolean allowed = false;
         UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
         for(UIComponent compc :component.getChildren()){
             System.err.println(compc.getId());

         }
         String help = component.getContainerClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
         System.err.println(help + "jaj");
         String id = component.getClientId();
         String contId =  component.getNamingContainer().getId();
         String name = (String) component.getAttributes().get("name");
         String parent = component.getParent().getId();


         System.err.println("testing id--- :" + id);
         System.err.println("testing name --- :" + name);
         System.err.println("testing container id --- :" + contId);
         System.err.println("testing parent id --- :" + parent);

         return false;
    }
```

In each case, I retrieved the parent element's id. The "for loop" that iterated through the children does return the desired child id, but I need to be certain of the component that is calling the getter. I need to take the "guess work" out of the equation.

Comment: Why without passing the client-id? (or the 'component' reserved param as I suspect you downvoted below) If you do not want developers to need to pass that in all the time, then wrap the component in a composite.

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, it is a design decision that was already in place. I was also looking for a quick solution. Since i will be implementing it with several other component types, creating a custom for each is not fee-sable at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code works:

```
public boolean isGlobalGetter(){
     UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
     String name = (String) component.getAttributes().get("name");

     if (name != null) {
         name = StringUtils.removeStart(name, ":");
         try {
             return this.getGlobalPermissionsMap().get(PAGE_NAME + "." + name).isAllowed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
     }
     return true;
}
```

It was returning the proper id all along after iterating through this code once over. I imagine this has to do with formulating the document object. This is why I must return 'true' the first time around. I might need to rethink this solution as I don't know how reliable it is.